# How do I create an arbitrary instance for a recursive datatype?

Tags: haskell

I think this creates arbitrary lists of length three, but how do I create lists of arbitrary length?

```
import Test.QuickCheck

data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary a  => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = do
    a <- arbitrary
    a' <- arbitrary
    a'' <- arbitrary
    return $ (Cons a (Cons a' (Cons a'' (Nil))))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [`sized`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:sized). It enables you to manage the size of the generated `arbitrary`, although the semantics are up to the instance:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a)  where
  arbitrary = sized go
    where go 0 = pure Nil
          go n = do
            xs <- go (n - 1)
            x  <- arbitrary
            return (Cons x xs)
```

For comparison, here is `[]`'s  [arbitrary instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#line-343):

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [a] where
  arbitrary = sized $ \n ->
    do k <- choose (0,n)
       sequence [ arbitrary | _ <- [1..k] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [`oneof`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#oneof) to pick either an empty list or recursively generate longer lists:

```
instance Arbitrary a  => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = 
    oneof [nil, cons]
    where nil = return Nil
          cons = do
            h <- arbitrary
            tl <- arbitrary
            return $ Cons h tl
```

here are a few tests:

```
λ> generate (arbitrary :: Gen (List Int))
Nil
λ> generate (arbitrary :: Gen (List Int))
Cons 4 (Cons 26 Nil)
λ> generate (arbitrary :: Gen (List Int))
Nil
```

---

remarks

as zeta pointed out this has the obvious flaw that you will generate probably very short lists:

- p(Nil) = 0.5
- p((_ `Cons` Nil) = 0.25
- p((_ `Cons` _ `Cons` Nil) = 0.125
- ...

as it will draw `Nil` with probability 0.5

Zetas solution does not have this problem!

You can get adapt these probability by using `frequency` instead of `oneof` if you like:

```
frequency [(1,nil), (4,cons)]
```

here you will have `p(Nil) = 0.2` and `p(Cons) = 0.8` but of course you can adapt this to your liking.

Another way is to realize that `List a` is isomorphic to `[a]` and reuse the `Arbitrary` instance for lists:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
    arbitrary = toList <$> arbitrary
```

**Thanks Zeta**

Comment: Given that `oneOf` will most likely use the same probability for all elements in the list, there's only a 50% chance to get a non-empty list, only 25% to get a list with one element, 12.5% to get a list with two elements, and so on. If you want that kind of behaviour (e.g. generate a list of length `n` with probability `2 ** (-n + 1)`, it's fine, but in general, this will lead to short lists.

Comment: yes that is true and your solution is obvious better and already got accepted - so do you want me to delete this?

Comment: Nah, but maybe you can find an alternative way to generate lists which are longer, e.g. `toList :: [a] -> List a` and `arbitrary = toList <$> arbitrary`, as an example for types that are isomorph to `[] a`.

Comment: well yes that's one possibility - of course you could use `frequency [(1,nil), (4,cons)]` too to bring this problem down a notch